# Firefox console getting SyntaxError: illegal character

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, spotify

I am trying to get the following code http://jsfiddle.net/qlmhuge/t7a1sh4u/ to work in wordpress 4.5.2. It is an example from the Spotify Web API html widgets. I am getting the following error:

> SyntaxError: illegal character {{#each albums.items}} on the # sign

The site that I am trying to run it on is here: http://dev-markandersonpianist.pantheonsite.io/discography/

Here is the script where I am getting the error:

```
<script id="results-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each albums.items}}
    <div style="background-image:url({{images.0.url}})" data-album-id="{{id}}" class="cover"><a href="{{external_urls.spotify}}"><div class="spotify-button"><img src="https://developer.spotify.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/play_on_spotify-green.png" /></div></a></div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

It works in jsFiddle as you can see above. I don't understand why it's not working in WordPress.

Comment: Are you sure that **handlebars.js** correctly installed to your page?

Comment: http://dev-markandersonpianist.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/themes/marksteinway/js/album-results.js?ver=1

I don't think you should be wrapping the handlebars code in `jQuery(function(){})`

Comment: I tried it without and it didn't work. I got the same error.

Comment: When I do a page source handlebars is shown loaded into the page. Is there anything else I can check?

Answer (score 0):

That's because of `{{#each albums.items}}` and `{{/each}}`.
`#` means you start a comment.
`/` means you start a RegExp.
`{` means you start describing an object.

Here, it's because of the two `{{`. You can't use an object as property label and property must be labeled in an object.

It looks like it's a template to generate code.
Be sure that the content is correctly generated before.
The browser can't understand the template generation code.

Comment: How do I check that the content is correctly generated before? There is another script that you can see in the jfiddle that depends on it.

Comment: Well, I just explained why there was a "syntax" errors. As for the working of the code, in JSFiddle you have a line `templateSource = document.getElementById('results-template').innerHTML` You don't want the code to be executed, so you could use something else than the "script" tag and hide it with CSS. `<code-template id="results-template"></code-template` is HTML5 valid. With a CSS `code-template { display:none; }` it would be invisible